# What happens to humans inside titans when they die?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In attack on titan, if someone were swallowed by a titan (it doesn't matter if the person if dead or alive) what happens to the body if a titan dies before it pukes them up?

Comment: The only way for answers to not be opinion based, would be if this was specifically discussed in the manga, or if the mangaka answered this in a Q&A session and it is documented.....Not having read the manga I cannot flag this as primarily opinion based, so if anyone else has a clue.....

Comment: @NZKshatriya: I have a feeling some titans that ate humans were killed at some point, so I think there should be some semblance of an educated guess that one could make. I _suspect_ that the bodies simply dissolve in stomach acid (doesn't that happen to part of Eren's body?) but I don't know for sure right now.

Comment: Has an answer here; [Can a human survive inside a titan?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/32032/can-a-human-survive-inside-a-titan) The question indirectly answers the question. *Now, assuming that somehow the human was swallowed wholly by a titan, and the human is in perfect condition, with the standard gear of the scouting legion, then he might be able to survive if someone were to kill the titan immediately after he was swallowed. If it took too long, then he won't survive*

Answer (score 1):

In theory, nothing happens. they would starve to death in the titan's stomach or commit suicide. Titans can't digest anything and therefore, don't need an acidic substance in their stomach.